# refreral link not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have a script made in code igniter but the script is not showing users refreral link it is displaying http:///admin
please can anyone tell me what im doing wrong

```
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding-left:20px;">Referral Link</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFAEA" class="upp" width="600px" align="left">
        <strong>http://<? echo $namaweb; ?>/<? echo $r["username"];?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows `http:///admin` because you have not set `$namaweb` (and should have gotten an error) and `$r["username"]` happens to be `admin`.

To "fix" the problem, just change/set the values.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 
    echo base_url() . $namaweb;
?>
```